# How to implement the API Samples? (VoiceRecognition)

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am very new to Android development and I am trying to create a very basic app that makes use of the VoiceRecognition facility.

The resource site here says to just paste the sample code into the project:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html

However eclipse doesn't seem to find/like the line "import com.example.android.apis.R", what it underlines is the com.example part of it, and as a result all the "R." methods give errors (e.g. findViewById(R.id.list))....

Is there something that I am not doing? Am I supposed to set up the project in a particular way in order to use these code samples?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the Google APIs installed in your environment.

For each SDK version you target, you can choose to use the one with the Google APIs or not. Speech input utilises the Google APIs so you must have them installed and target them in your app and Eclipse.

---

EDIT:

Detailed instructions for using the Google APIs in Eclipse can be found on the [Google Maps Overview](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html) page.

You'll need to pay particular attention to the [Set up a new Android project](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#projectsetup) section (which also covers reconfiguring an existing project) and [Set up an Android Virtual Device](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#avdsetup). You may or may not need to reference the speech library in a similar way to the [Add a uses-library element](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html#useslibrary) section.

Comment: Yes I have the APIs installed, I was able to run the API project on my phone... how do I make sure that i am targeting them in Eclipse?